# Spree commerce installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, spree

```
casionwoo@casionwoo-desktop:~/mystore$ bundle install
Updating https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git
Updating https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (= 2.0.3) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3.2.8) ruby

    rails (4.0.0)
```

i am installing spree for setting i don't know why this error occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
# 3.2.4.rc1

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:      https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'spree', '2.0.3'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch =>     '2-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git',     :branch => '2-0-stable'
```

this is my Gemfile source code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `gem 'rails', '4.0.0'` on your Gemfile to `gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.8'`. There is no stable version of Spree compatible with Rails 4 yet.

PS: You might need to run `bundle update rails` afterwards.

Comment: rails (= 3.2.8) ruby depends on
      railties (= 3.2.8) ruby

    sass-rails (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on                                                                   this error occured again do you know why?
      railties (4.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Spree version

gem 'spree', '~> 3.0.8'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.0.0'

is compatible with

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'